# How to add contents of 2 fields to get summary in XAML code?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I would like to know how to get the column summary in XAML code. I'm able to get the row summaries using the code mentioned in attachment or image.
But I do not know how to add contents from "a1" ,"b1" and "c1" to get the "Summary" in XAML code only without using code-behind . I'm using Infragistics xamDataGrid

[please refer this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoj6p.jpg)

Comment: No information is give.
What are you using? working directly in EXCEL? using DataGrid?
Give us some code man!

Comment: Hi MichaelThePotato,Sorry, Please click on "please refer this" hyperlink. I tried copying code but it did not take for some reason. So I have mentioned in that link. Yes I'm using infragistics xamDataGrid control in XAML code. Yes reading data from xamDataGrid's cells.

Comment: You think people at SO are super human who can see through your mind. After seeing the image, its still not clear what you are trying to do ? And where are "Salary" and "Bonus"  to get the TotalAmount .

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I re-edited the question. I would like to know how to add the contents from a1,b1,c1 to get the summary using xamDataGrid and XAML. TIA

Comment: @ganeshshsf again unclear ! do you want to show 7, 10, 14 as shown in the figure ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I want to know how to show the results as 10,6,15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `MultiBinding` and `MultiValueConverter`. Below example calculates sum of Num1 and Num2 properties and shows their Sum.

```
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sum">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SumCnvKey}">
                        <Binding Path="Num1"/>
                        <Binding Path="Num2"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Converter:

```
public class SumConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[1] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue && values[2] != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)

            return ((int)values[0] + (int)values[1]).ToString();

        else
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! But that logic [means calculation part] can be written only in XAML code using Infragistics controls and it's properties? Without writing C# code?

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your help.